# what is the use of " .format(**config)) "

Tags: ros, opencv, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure/Tutorials/SettingUpDynamicReconfigureForANode%28python%29

in this link ^, they have this piece of code (shown below)

```
rospy.loginfo("Config set to {int_param}, {double_param}, {str_param}, {bool_param}, {size}".**format(**config))**
```

what is the use of the bold part in the above code snippet ^

I am trying to dynamically reconfigure values of upper and lower HSV range values, so do I need to use this .format thing at the end of

```
lower_red=np.array([lowerh,lowers,lowerv])
```

if not, then what is its use?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270247/what-is-the-use-of-%22--.format(**config))--"/) by [MukulKhanna](https://answers.ros.org/users/31696/mukulkhanna/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2017-09-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-05**:
I formatted the code in your question. To format your code please use the `101010` button *not* `"`.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-05**:
Do you literally mean

```
**format(**config)**
```

or do you mean

```
format(**config)
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm assuming that you mean

```
rospy.loginfo("Config set to {int_param}, {double_param}, {str_param}, {bool_param}, {size}".format(**config))
```

This is just plain Python. From [the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)

> `str.format(*args, **kwargs)`
>
> Perform a string formatting operation. The string on which this method is called can contain literal text or replacement fields delimited by braces `{}`. Each replacement field contains either the numeric index of a positional argument, or the name of a keyword argument. Returns a copy of the string where each replacement field is replaced with the string value of the corresponding argument.

As for the `**config`, checkout this [answer on StackOverlfow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36926/3562890):

> This is a shortcut that allows you to pass multiple arguments to a function directly using either a list/tuple or a dictionary.

As for using it with `numpy`, I'm not too familiar with `numpy` but I don't believe that you do. But, you should ask a new question about that specifically.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-05**:
I believe that I originally quoted the wrong part of the correct docs so I updated my answer to the correct part.